# Not all image properties retrieved with Image.PropertyItems

Tags: c#, .net, image, exif

I am trying to get a list of all the `EXIF` tags in a given image.
using the `Image.propertyItems[]` array, I can enumerate all of the items that instance of the image object reads, and output their ID.

I see there are items that ARE NOT listed there, that other applications including windows explorer seem to have no issue retrieving.

E.G. in the following code...

```
Image img = new Bitmap("C:\\IMAG0648.jpg");
foreach (PropertyItem property in img.PropertyItems)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine(property.Id);
  }
```

I get a listing of *most* of the items, specifically though I am missing (among possibly others) the `0x010F` and `0x0110`. I know these items *are* there because I can open the same image in another EXIF editor like PhotoME, and they are clearly there, and clearly labeled as the correct ID.

Are there nesting levels in the `EXIF` and I am not walking out far enough, or is there some reason this would not work in its basic form above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ExifLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET-2-0) - there is a demo project with source that extracts all tags from an image that you could use.

Edit: I'm going to append my answer to explain why I believe the .Net Image class doesn't handle all EXIF tags as we might expect.  However, I'm going to leave my initial link and suggestion above as I believe it's the best option in the end.

Ok, on to the **Why**:

My testing described below used images where Windows 7 showed EXIF data for make and model (by right clicking on file > Properties > 'Details' tab > 'Camera' section), but in .Net the `PropertyItems` do not contain these same EXIF tags.  Images taken with the HTC One were mentioned in another answer, so I found images that satisfy my test [here](http://www.colbybrownphotography.com/gear-review-a-photographers-take-on-the-htc-one/).  (Specifically, I used original-2.jpg, original-4.jpg, and original-8.jpg from this webpage.)

First, I looked at `img.PropertyItems.Count()` and got 32. So there is data in there!  (Clearly, we know Windows 7 in my case is seeing the EXIF tags).  But, when I iterate over the `.PropertyItems` and look at each `Id` (per your original question):

- I get 32 results
- I don't get resulting Ids of 271 (0x010F - Camera Make) or 272 (0x0110 - Camera Model)
- I did get 282, 283, 296, 305, 306, and 27 other 5 digit ids
- If I use `img.PropertyItems.Single(x => x.Id == 305).Value` I do get the SoftwareUsed (or if I use 206 I get the DateTime) EXIF property

**So, to your point, why is the .Net Image class not seeing the EXIF tags with Ids of 271/272 (again, Camera Make/Model)?**

I dug into ExifLib's source code (link at top of answer) a little bit and think I see what's happening:

- If you look at the `private byte[] GetTagBytes(...)` method in ExifReader.cs (line 655) you'll see that byte offsets are used to find the 'Exif IDF' and total space per tag
- This method returns a specific byte array that is then converted to the proper data type
- If that type is an ASCII string - null characters are removed and date formats are adjusted

So it would seem that the .Net Image class is able to return the EXIF tag properly via `PropertyItems` when there **aren't** any byte offsets in play.

Using ExifDataView (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/exif_data_view.html) I was able to validate this:

- I found I was **always** able to use .Net to properly retrieve Make and Model when the value length is 4 ("HTC" + null character)
- I was **never** able to use .Net when the length was 5 ("HTC" + null + null?)
- In my test above (with the original-4.jpg image) the SoftwareUsed and DateTime tags worked because the length of these tags were (string length) + 1 for the null character.  The Camera Make tag length was (string length) + 2 and didn't work.  This seems to thrown everything off.

The ExifLib code handles these offsets and/or multiple null characters correctly and .Net does not.

The result is the .Net Image class doesn't iterate over these properties as part of `PropertyItems` and returns a 'Sequence contains no matching element' when using `image.PropertyItems.Single(x => x.Id == tagMake).Value`

**Bottom line: use ExifLib or some other 3rd party library designed to handle extracting EXIF data if you want to it work on all images properly.  Use the .Net Image class if you want it to work some of the time when the bytes are just right :-)**

Comment: I have looked at other solutions, that having been one of them, and I appreciate the input, one of those may end up being what I finally use. However the purpose of this is to understand why the .NET image class is skipping over these items whereas others seem to pick them up. To me at this stage it represents a bug or a misunderstanding on my part, since though it is specific to the image source, other software products do not seem to have the issue.

Comment: That sir, is exactly what I was looking for, a solution or a verifiable lack of support for the native .NET classes. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The tags you are specifying are certainly there, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms534416.aspx). This is working for me with [this sample image](http://www.exiv2.org/sample.html)

[image: Sample image with EXIF metadata]

```
int tagMake = 0x010F;  // 271
int tagModel = 0x0110; // 272

Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\image.jpg");

byte[] make = image.PropertyItems.Single(x => x.Id == tagMake).Value;
byte[] model = image.PropertyItems.Single(x => x.Id == tagModel).Value;

var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(make));  // Returns: Canon
Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(model)); // Returns: Canon PowerShot S40
```

Comment: Very strange, if I run both mine and your code against *that* image, I get the tags, against the one from my HTC one Smartphone I get them from neither section of code. Things like ExifTool show them all on both images, and they both report to be EXIF v2.2 so I would assume that they both have the same format. I could accept one corrupt image, but all the images taken with both my HTC one and my wife's Note3, all have this same issue of not being able to see this in .NET, but can in any other editor. So suggestions on where to even begin to look deeper?

Comment: @Sabre You could try a 3rd party command-line tool, though. Or, you could try to list all the properties in `image.PropertyItems` and see if the properties you are looking for use different IDs.

Comment: I have done both, that is part of the problem. All of the third party tools show the tags there, and of the same ID. Image.PropertyItems[] does not show these tags to exist on those photos. And the code *does* read those tags from other images. So I am trying to understand why other programs can see them, but .NET can not on the same images? Every editor / viewer *other* than .net has picked them up without issue, and I can clearly see them in a hex editor. Plus being able to see the correct tags in other images leads me to believe the code is correct....

Comment: Obviously it has something to do with them images themselves, but why others work and .NET fails is the crux of the issue.

Comment: @Sabre Yeah, it`s weird, for sure. I'd love to test with your image, though!

Comment: http://207.192.195.114/img.zip That contains both the sample downloaded per your suggestion, and two of the other images.